# Android Studio onCreate setContentView

Tags: android, setcontentview

I started a blank project and modified the onCreate by adding the below but the button is not being created because I can not see it in the design view. What am I doing wrong, I expected to see the button with its text as indicated.

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("Hello Button");
setContentView(b);
```

Many thx

Comment: did you run the project on a device or emulator?  AFAIK design view is for xml based layouts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are creating a layout through code, you will not see it in the XML view. If you build and run the app, you should see the `Button` appear.

If you would rather see the `Button` in the XML view, you should modify the main_layout.xml to look like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am a Button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can get a reference to this `Button` in your Java code by using the following code **after** calling setContentView():

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```